# How to print Mouse Coordinates TASM

Tags: assembly, x86, mouse, interrupt, tasm

```
TITLE MP3
.model small
.stack 100h
.data 
x  dw 0     
nwln db 13,10,"$" 
y  dw 0     
coordsx db "X: $"
coordsy db "Y: $"   

.code     

printf proc
    mov dx,bx
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    ret
printf endp

newline proc
    lea dx,nwln
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    ret
newline endp

scanf proc
    mov dx, bx
    mov ah, 0ah
    int 21h
    ret
scanf endp 


getx proc



    ret
getx endp   

START:
    MOV AX,@data
    MOV DS,AX
    mov ES,AX



    mov al,13h
    mov ah,0
    int 10h

        mov ax, 0
        int 33h

        mov ax, 1
        int 33h


     lea bx,coordsx
     call printf
     call newline
     lea bx, coordsy
     call printf
     call newline
     call newline   
     lea bx,line
     call printf
     call newline
     lea bx, circle
     call printf


      mov cx, 0002
    mov dx, 0024

start1:  



    mov x,cx
    mov y,dx  

    lea bx,coordsx
     call printf


    mov ax, 3
    int 33h     




    jmp start1


fin:
       mov ah,4ch
       int 21h        

end start
```

We are stuck with this code and we need to print the coordinates of the mouse. we understand that the mouse coordinates are in cx and dx but we can't display it inside the loop. we printed the "x:"and "Y:" outside the loop so it wont print multiple times. tracking the mouse coordinates in real time

Example output:
             X:1ABC
             Y:0020

Comment: ...so if I get it, you need to print a hexadecimal value of `CX` and `DX` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is to convert integer number into string. This can be done simply:

```
; AX = number to be printed
; DS:DI = location for the string
itoa:
    pusha
    mov cx, ax  
    mov bx, 10
    divloop:
        xor dx, dx
        div bx  

        add dl, 48          ;start of the ASCII table
        mov byte [di], dl
        inc di

        test ax, ax 
        jnz divloop

    mov byte [di], 0
    popa
    ret
```

This procedure must be called

```
somePlaceInMemory: times 6 db 0 

....

lea bx, coordsx
call printf

mov ax, bx
mov di, somePlaceInMemory
call itoa
mov bx, di
call printf
```